# Bad Message when using SSH to CreateDirectory using NT Authentication

Tags: ssh, sftp

I am using the Renci SSH library to create an SFTP directory on a server. The issue I am seeing is that when I use an account set up to use NT Authentication in the freeFTPd SFTP server settings, I am getting a "bad message" exception returned. If I use an account set up to use a password stored as SHA1 hash, I get no such exception. When I look in the server log for the SFTP server, I see an "Access Denied" log entry corresponding to the "Bad Message" exception.

Why I am seeing a cryptic "Bad Message" error being returned from the CreateDirectory call instead of an Access Denied error? An end user seeing that error message would have no idea what it means.

Comment: Don't use freeFTPd. It's outdated.

Comment: What SFTP client/server software do you suggest/recommend to use instead that is free and is as robust and well documented as freeFTPd?

Comment: "Robust and well documented" - freeFTPd? You must be kidding! Anyway, ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. This is Q&A about programming.